# Accept Bluetooth Pairing Request Automatically without GUI

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian, bluez

I would like to know whether there is a way to accept incoming pairing requests from smartphones to Raspberry Pi 3 with bluetoothctl or bluez. I have tried NoInputNoOutput agent and also modified simple-agent.py. However, a window for accepting these pairing request still appears for manually accepting and the pairing isn't completed without the user clicking the OK button. I do not want any window to appear and instead all pairing request should be accepted automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any progress on this? others may be searching for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at this:
https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c212.html
It seems to cover what you are looking for.
Please tell me if this helped!

Comment: No, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I spent some times to deal with the same problem. So I hope this answer can be useful for other people.

The bluetoothctl daemon deals with incoming pairing request, scanning etc and the same are made by the Bluetooth GUI. If you remove from the GUI the Bluetooth stuff (right click on the icon and then remove) and then open a terminal and run:

```
bluetoothctl
agent NoInputNoOutput
```

incoming pairing request will be automatically accepted.

As countercheck, before removing your Bluetooth GUI if you run the aforementioned commands without accepting on the pop-up dialog you should see `Paired: yes` in the log.

According to your application, I suggest removing the Bluetooth GUI and working with bluetoothctl

Comment: This command works and I get `Connected:yes` but it reverts back to `no` in 5 seconds or so. Any idea why thats happening?

Comment: Which type of devices are involved? Sometimes they can disconnect few seconds just after the connection due to timing mismatch between the two devices.

Comment: raspberry pi 4 and one plus nord n100(Android) . Also this only works if phone is detected earlier but not paired correctly. If this phone was never discovered by raspberry pi before , this doesnt work.